# Android Logcat error

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Anyone can tell me what's the reason behind this run-time error?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

i'm trying to make a PDF reader app following Joe Blough's Android PDF Viewer library at GitHub: https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library. I followed everything and I end up with this error.

```
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.traininghandouts.app/com.traininghandouts.app.PdfViewer}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.traininghandouts.app.PdfViewer
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.traininghandouts.app.PdfViewer
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
12-20 03:43:14.037: E/AndroidRuntime(29822):    ... 11 more
```

---

here's my code:

```
try{
  String path =  "mnt/sdcard/android-android-ui-design-patterns.pdf";

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, PdfViewer.class);
  intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
  startActivity(intent);


}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InstantiationException:

> Thrown when a program attempts to access a constructor which is not
>   accessible from the location where the reference is made.

That came from [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/InstantiationException.html)

I can't say what EXACTLY caused your exception, but if you post the entirety of the error from Logcat and the line where the exception happens, or a block of code where the exception happens, that may help a little more.

Comment: @nhqdualcagony I'm honestly not sure what is causing the issue. Do you know which line of code is causing the problem? Unfortunately, your Logcat does not seem to show what line number the problem lies at.

Comment: yah, can't figure it out either

Comment: @nhqdualcagony If you zip your entire project and upload it (maybe to multiupload.com) I could look and see if I can figure it out, if you want.

Comment: its just like this: http://pastebin.com/NZ72yTtG then followed what's in the GitHub