# Titanium Studio - Errors when running Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to run the **default** project in the Android Emulator on Mac OS X 10.8.2. According to the getting started screen my Android setup is all good, and I have installed all the necessary files that the getting started guide tells me to.

But when I run the app in the Android emulator, it shows a whole lot of errors in the console.

These are the errors I am getting: http://pastebin.com/fGBn9b35

The thing is though, it shows all these errors, but at the end of it all, the app appears in the emulator as normal, although it takes several minutes to show, and I want to get rid of all these errors.

Anybody know why it's messing up so much?

Answer (score 1):

> Your Logcat shows all normal. It's true that you have problem with
>   Battery,GPS, SoundPool,etc  in emulator. Make sure you don't have
>   application level Issues.
>
> Do basic Research before you post
>
> [Android logcat errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403330/android-logcat-errors)
>
> [Android Logcat error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570310/android-logcat-error)